# Magento - Selling from category page with no product page

Tags: magento

Is it possible to have an active product show on a category page, but not have its own product page?

Where my products are very similar I want to sell them from a category page, hence the product does not need its own product page.

I know i can use XML in the category design tab to create/customise my own category page without product title links.

But is it possible to use XML on the product design tab to stop the products form being shown individually?

Comment: Have you looked into creating either a configurable or grouped product for those products?

Comment: That may be a plan, but i have so many products i thought it would look better on a single category page.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make sense.  Why display products in the first place that customers cannot navigate to?  Wouldn't that be confusing to the user?

Comment: What should happen, if a customer clicks on the product-link on a category page? Do you also have php experience? One simple possibility would be to just remove the link to the detail page from the product listing. The product pages will still be there, but no one would know about them. In particular they won't be indexed by google.

Comment: Axel, I'm sure it makes sense.! if it is a real basic product and the image does all the talking. The product descriptions are very similar for this category. Selling from a main category page would work in this case.

Comment: Jan Wy, Yes i can easily have a custom category page with no link to the individual product page. I was thinking of adding a canonical link from the product page back to the category.